# How to filter items by some value using filter form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have items, that have price, color, manufacturer, model and so on. I want users to filter items by price range, manufacturer, model at the same time. For example: show all cars with manufacturer "Ford", model "Mustang" and price from 1k to 10k.

For pagination results i want use will_paginate (and submit form with ajax). I am looking for some "first bricks" or "first steps" to solve my problem. If i miss some good *new* tutorials, pls, feel free to give links :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this with a where query in your controller:

```
@records = Stuff.select("stuffs.*")

@records = @records.where("model = ?", model) if filter_car
@records = @records.where("price >= ? and price <= ?", price) if filter_price
@records = @records.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => params[:per_page])
```

Comment: thx, i did like you said. if there are some other cool variants, i am ready to listen :)

Comment: For those who comes here later, might be better to put this in your model instead of your controller. Keep your controller slim :)